# Installing DXA into an existing BluePrint

Tags: dxa

When installing STRI/DXA into an existing BluePrint we add the existing Publications as children of the `100 Master` but there are several Structure Groups and Pages that have to be added manually into each existing Publication:

- `assets` Structure Group
- `assets/css` Structure Group
- `assets/fonts` Structure Group
- `assets/images` Structure Group
- `assets/scripts` Structure Group
- `_System/Publish HTML Design` Page

Is there a specific reason why these are not in the BluePrint at the `100 Master` level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These Structure Groups have been defined on the `400 Example Site` level, since they are required by the `Publish HTML Design` Page which is also created on the same level. We split Schemas and Templates from the content and website items this way. We specifically chose not to use a diamond model BluePrint, since it needed to be understandable by novice users too.

When importing in a existing BluePrint (please note this feature wasn't documented because it wasn't fully completed nor tested), you can import the `website-only.zip` in your content and/or website Publication(s). The Structure Groups and Pages are all in there.

If you want to import the content and the Pages into separate Publications, you will probabaly want to use Content Porter and manually select the items from the `website-only.zip`, since the import script, can currently only import the entire package into a single Publication.

Comment: Thanks Bart - with regards your comment on _'feature wasn't documented because it wasn't fully completed nor tested'_ - does this mean that it is supported now if we manually import using the _website-only.zip_ ?

Comment: @Dylan..MarkSaunders as far as support goes on this, you are welcome to use it, as documented inside the script :p.

Comment: Great to know you guys are there for us!. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The reason these Structure Groups are not at the **100 Master** level is the same as the reason that you would not create other Structure Groups for your web applications at the 100 Master level. This level does not contain any content or web structure/pages. The Structure Groups you mention are only needed for (DXA specific) web sites, so should be created lower down in the blueprint at an appropriate level for sharing across all DXA websites.

Imagine for example that you wanted to implement DXA for microsites within an existing (non-DXA) Tridion implementation blueprint. You would not want all your existing (non-DXA) sites to inherit this DXA specific stuff.